# \tau \epsilon \chi ! Missing $ inserted

Tags: beamer, pdftex

Beginner here with an issue on a simple presentation using beamer

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \tau \epsilon \chi
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The above fails with the message "! Missing $ inserted." and waits for me to do something when converting to pdf. I have tried adding the instruction `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and also `\usepackage[greek]{babel}`. I have not seen references either to needing to use any other package. What is exactly I am missing?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. You have to write `$\tau \epsilon \chi$` to make it work, because these commands are only valid in math mode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to put mathematics inside *math-mode*, which you do by enclosing it in `$...$`, for in-line equations, or `\[...\]` for displayed equations:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  $\tau \epsilon \chi$

 For displayed equations:
 \[ \tau \epsilon \chi \]

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. Clearly I missed something when reading about LaTeX

Answer (score 4):

From your question, I suggest `\tau \epsilon \chi` as **text** you want to typeset.

This solution allows your greek text to fit nicely into text:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand{\textgreek}[1]{\begingroup\fontencoding{LGR}\selectfont#1\endgroup}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        This \textgreek{teq} fits nicely in some text.

        This $\tau \epsilon \chi$ fits not so nice.
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: rendering]

Reference for the encoding: [page 36](http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/doc/encguide.pdf)

If you want to stick to the names of the greek letters, you could use the `textgreek` package, e.g.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        This \texttau \textepsilon \textchi~fits nicely in some text.

        This $\tau \epsilon \chi$ fits not so nicely.
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

to produce the same result.

Comment: I think I did try to use textgreek. But somehow it failed for me. I will try again, as is possible that I was getting things mixed up

Comment: Even if you use textgreek, you have to use `\texttau` instead of `\tau` and so on.